# Array of arrays json Javascript, ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, request, response

Im trying to access to parameter value from response.

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "",
        dataType: 'text',
        async: false,
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)
        },
        data: '{ "action" : "create", "resource" : {"name" : "teddssssssssddsssdsddddsdddwdsdssdsddi",  "description": "Test Tenant Description","parent": {"href": "localhost"}}}',
        success: function(as) {
            alert(as[0][0]["id"]);          
        }
  });
```

in the success area i got the response, in json. I want to access to the id value, but i cant. always says undefined, i tried different options.
this is the response format.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "href": "localhost/1111111",
      "id": "100000000111",
      "name": "test",
      "ancestry": "1000011111",
      "divisible": true,
      "description": "Test Tenant Description",
      "use_config_for_attributes": false,
      "default_miq_group_id": "10021200000173"
    }
  ]
}
```

I dont know if i can access direct to the parameter or better get the response as text and split.

Comment: try with `as["results"][0]["id"]`

Comment: Never ever use `async:false`. It is a terrible practice and is deprecated by the browser vendors. You should be seeing warning about that in console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response has a different structure.
Your response is an object with one property and value is an array of objects.

something like {'results': [...{}]}

Key 0 does not exist.

```js
const data = {"results":[{"href":"localhost/1111111","id":"100000000111","name":"test","ancestry":"1000011111","divisible":true,"description":"Test Tenant Description","use_config_for_attributes":false,"default_miq_group_id":"10021200000173"}]};


console.log(data.results[0].id);
```

Comment: This answer works, i had to change datatype to json. Thanks